# Using "keys()" in python3.4 in win7

Tags: python, function, windows-7, key, python-3.4

I'm reading *Natural Language Processing with Python* by Steven Bird, Ewan Klein, Edward Loper.
And in this book, they use python2.4 or 2.5, but I could get python3.4.1 and python3.3 and python2.7.1. So I can1t use keys().

Please tell me how to use python2.4 or 2.5, or how to make "keys()" on myself.
I know the concept of function so I will make keys() with some hints, please help me!

Comment: Python 3 has `dict.keys()`. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: And you can use Python 2.7, instead of 2.4 or 2.5. Just about everything that works in 2.4 and 2.5 will work just fine in 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use a book designed for Python 2.4 or 2.5, you can use Python 2.7 and not have any problems.

Python 3 `dict.keys()` exists and works just fine. It returns a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) rather than a list like in Python 2, so all you have to do to get the same result is call `list(somedict.keys())`.

However, you'll have other problems translating the Python 2 code to Python 3, and I strongly advice you to stick with a Python 2.x interpreter.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and advice!I'm going to master Natural Language Processing, not python3.4.1.So I　will recieve your advice to use python2.7.Some other functions has another work from the book, if I can do as on the book, it's very happy.Very nice advice,　Regard

Comment: dict.keys() had worked!Thank you! But .keys() had worked too! What a amaging! I am noob!